# Passing Parameters in action listener event in a custom tag

Tags: jsf, el

In continuation of building a custom tag, all the processes have been done and are working accurately except passing parameters to beans method.  i have tried but unable to pass the parameters, following is the code.

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/pinnacleTags.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

tabib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>pinnacleTags/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>PinnacleCombo</tag-name>
        <source>buttonPanel.xhtml</source>
        <attribute>
            <name>textBoxValue</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>caption</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>btnCaption</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>textBoxWidth</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>btnHeight</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>btnWidth</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>actionListenerBean</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>actionListenerBean</name>
            <method-signature>void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)</method-signature>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>actionListenerMethod</name>
            <method-signature>method-signature="java.lang.String action(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)"</method-signature>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

the component

```
        <ui:composition> 
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{caption}" />
                <p:inputText value="#{textBoxValue}" style="width: #{textBoxWidth}; " />
                <p:commandButton type = "submit" 
                                 value = "#{btnCaption}" 
                                 actionListener="#{actionListenerBean[actionListenerMethod]}"
                                 style="height: #{btnHeight}; width: #{btnWidth};" />
            </div>
        </ui:composition>
```

and finally the useage

```
            <pt:PinnacleCombo id="clientID" 
                                textBoxValue="#{customTags.clientID}"
                                caption="Client ID: " 
                                textBoxWidth="150px" 
                                btnHeight="35px" 
                                btnCaption="Press"
                                actionListenerBean="#{customTags}"
                                actionListenerMethod="btnPressed"/>
```

I donot know how to pass parameters to the menthod, pls suggest.

Comment: This is BTW not a composite component but a custom tag.

Comment: thanx for the correction, may u pls suggest how to pass parameters to the method???

Comment: Try removing the `method-signature`s. The bean should be an object, and the method simply the name of the method.

Comment: @jasper-de-vries i tried removing as u mentioned but no success.

Comment: Did you inspect http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam ? It allows passing methidExpressions with parameters but not sure if it fits your requirements.

Comment: @Selaron thanx a lot, got the right possible way to accopmlish the task.. and it is simple too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally as @Selaron suggested, the custom tag, after using omnifaces, is

```
        <ui:composition> 
            <h:outputLabel value="#{caption}" />
            <p:inputText value="#{textBoxValue}" style="width: #{textBoxWidth}; " />
            <o:methodParam name="method" value="#{actionListenerBeanMethod}" />
            <p:commandButton type = "submit" 
                             value = "#{btnCaption}" 
                             actionListener="#{method}"
                             style="height: #{btnHeight}; width: #{btnWidth};" />
        </ui:composition>
```

and the function call was simple

```
actionListenerBeanMethod="#{customTags.btnPressed('Value Passed')}"
```

Thanx @Selaron for help.